# Access Google Analytics data for a tracking id associated with a deleted domain?

Tags: google-analytics

We just deleted and recreated a Google apps domain for the purposes of merging two domains into one. We found out after the fact that there was a Google Analytics account associated with the old deleted domain.

Is there any way to get the Analytics data associated with the tracking ids still out there on web sites?

I'm thinking no but I wanted to check.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you can still access the GA account to get historic data, even if the website that it was associated with doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Google does not care if the website still exists or not. However you need Access to a Google Account that is associated with the account.